# issue using imbalanced dataset with logloss and RFECV

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, rfe

I am using imbalanced dataset(54:38:7%) with RFECV for feature selection like this:

```
# making a multi logloss metric
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss, make_scorer
log_loss_rfe = make_scorer(score_func=log_loss, greater_is_better=False)

# initiating Light GBM classifier
lgb_rfe = LGBMClassifier(objective='multiclass', learning_rate=0.01, verbose=0, force_col_wise=True,
                         random_state=100, n_estimators=5_000, n_jobs=7)

# initiating RFECV
rfe = RFECV(estimator=lgb_rfe, min_features_to_select=2, verbose=3, n_jobs=2, cv=3, scoring=log_loss_rfe)
# fitting it
rfe.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)
```

And I got an error, presumably because the subsamples sklearn's RFECV has made doesn't have all of the classes from my data. I had no issues fitting the very same data outside of RFECV.

Here's the complete error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)

_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 431, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 285, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 262, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 222, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 37, in _rfe_single_fit
    return rfe._fit(
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 259, in _fit
    self.scores_.append(step_score(estimator, features))
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 39, in <lambda>
    lambda estimator, features: _score(
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 674, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 199, in __call__
    return self._score(partial(_cached_call, None), estimator, X, y_true,
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 242, in _score
    return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred,
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 2265, in log_loss
    raise ValueError("y_true and y_pred contain different number of "
ValueError: y_true and y_pred contain different number of classes 3, 2. Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument. Classes found in y_true: [0 1 2]
"""


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-9-5feb62a6f457> in <module>
      1 rfe = RFECV(estimator=lgb_rfe, min_features_to_select=2, verbose=3, n_jobs=2, cv=3, scoring=log_loss_rfe)
----> 2 rfe.fit(X=X_train, y=y_train)

~/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py in fit(self, X, y, groups)
    603             func = delayed(_rfe_single_fit)
    604 
--> 605         scores = parallel(
    606             func(rfe, self.estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
    607             for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))

~/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1052 
   1053             with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1054                 self.retrieve()
   1055             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1056             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

~/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    931             try:
    932                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 933                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    934                 else:
    935                     self._output.extend(job.get())

~/ds_jup_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    540         AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541         try:
--> 542             return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543         except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544             raise TimeoutError from e

1 frames

/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py in __get_result(self)
    386     def __get_result(self):
    387         if self._exception:
--> 388             raise self._exception
    389         else:
    390             return self._result

ValueError: y_true and y_pred contain different number of classes 3, 2. Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument. Classes found in y_true: [0 1 2]
```

How to fix this to be able to select features recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log-loss needs the probability predictions, not the class predictions, so you should add

```py
log_loss_rfe = make_scorer(score_func=log_loss, needs_proba=True, greater_is_better=False)
```

The error is because without that, the passed `y_pred` is one-dimensional (classes 0,1,2) and `sklearn` [assumes it's a binary classification](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L2254) problem and those predictions are probability of the positive class.  To deal with that, it adds on the probability of the negative class, but then there are only two columns compared to your three classes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying *stratified* cross-validation, which will try to preserve the fraction of samples for each class. Experiment with one of these scikit-learn cross-validators:
[`sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html?highlight=stratified#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold),
[`StratifiedShuffleSplit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html?highlight=stratified#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit),
[`RepeatedStratifiedKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold.html?highlight=stratified#sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold), replacing `cv=3` in your `RFECV` with the chosen cross-validator.

**Edit**
I have missed the fact that `StratifiedKFold` is the default cross-validator in `RFECV`. Actually, the error is related to `log_loss_rfe`, which was defined with `needs_proba=False`. Credit to @BenReiniger!

Comment: This (`StratifiedKFold`) is already the default behavior for `RFECV` with multiclass `y` and integer/`None` values for `cv`.